# Why does my 100% wide element become 30000px+ wide when using css3-mediaqueries.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

Here is a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/TKX9j/3/

```
(function($) {
    var foo = $('#foo');
    foo.css('width', "").css('width', foo.width());
    foo.text('This is '+foo.css('width')+' wide.');
})(jQuery);
```

As you can see, I'd rely on resetting and getting the width of the element, but I get a huge number. Why? It doesn't happen when I set to `onLoad` on the left. `No wrap - in <head>` is not relevant. I can't wait for `onLoad` in my production code.

I'm using this:
http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Answer (score 0):

This is because the browser has not determined with width of the element yet, so it likely just returns some garbage value.

If possible try setting a default width in the CSS, then you will get that size even before the onLoad event.

Comment: That's what I thought by why is that js file doing it? It works when it's not present. Also, how do I set a default value that is replaced with the real 100% as soon as it would not be garbage?